Probability of getting pair from a deck of cards (AABCD)
I have seen lots of answers for this question based on combinations. But what about if we base it off of permutations. I have gotten this far.
$$={(52×3×48×44×40)({5!\over2!})\over(52\times51\times50\times49\times48)}$$
Here, I multiplied the numerator by 5! to rearrange all the cards and divided by 2! to remove the duplicates because the 2 pair cards are the same. However, I know this answer is wrong. The correct answer is:
$$={(52×3×48×44×40)({5!\over 2!3!})\over(52\times51\times50\times49\times48)}$$
How can this be? We should not have to divide by 3! as the 3 other cards are distinct.
Please help ... I have been looking at this for awhile.

The unordered collection ${A,A,B,C,D}$ is the same as ${A,A,C,D,B}$ and so on.  That's the $3!$

@lulu thanks for your comment! I thought that we only divided by the 3! if the objects were identical. But they are not ... they would be different cards with different values. How does that work? I appreciate any elaboration you could give. Thanks.

Just work a simpler question: count the three card hands with no pair.

Much can be learnt from your attempt to wrongly compute for two pairs.
If you just eliminate the $5!$ in the numerator (which is meaningless in the context), you will find that you will get the correct answer.
The question you may ask is why are we  dividing  your numerator $52\cdot3\cdot48\cdot3\cdot44$ by $8$ ? That is because

By $52\cdot3$ you are double counting ($A_1A_2\; and\; A_2A_1)$ Ditto for  ($B_1B_2\; and\; B_2B_1)$
Further, A group coming before B group and vice-versa also double counts.
Thus in totality you have counted $2^3 =8$ times higher

My earnest advice to you is that so far as poker is concerned, use combinations to avoid confusion and errors. Computations using combinations can be seen here and if you go through various types of hands, you will find a uniform systematic approach.
For some problems, permutations may give an easier solution, but not for poker.
Ypu can see how transparent the formula using combinations becomes:
$$Pr = \dfrac{\binom{13}2\left[\binom42\right]^2\binom{11}1\binom41}{\binom{52}5}$$

I apologize, this was my first time posting. I had no concept of the etiquette.

Ok, glad to have been of help !

It's $ 5\choose 2$ ways to pick two of the five draws to be the same. The $\frac{5!}{2!}$ will overcount by six times the number of permutations for some hands. For example, the following are equivalent but will be over-counted:

$(A,A,2,3,4)$
$(A,A,2,4,3)$
$(A,A,4,3,2)$
$(A,A,4,2,3)$
$(A,A,3,4,2)$
$(A,A,3,2,4)$

Thus, $\frac{5!}{2!}$ assumes only one of these six will be counted in the original $(52×3×48×44×40)$

That makes sense! But, how would it translate to this example for the probability of two pairs - where do the 2!s come from?: $$= {(52x3x48x3x44) x ({5!\over2!x2!x2!})\over(52x51x50x49x48)}$$

What are you talking about? There's no 2!2!2!, $5 \choose 2$ means 5 choose 2 and is represented as $\frac{5!}{2!3!}$

@JJMae My example was for the possibility of 2 pairs, so AABBC.
